# NullReferenceException from wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, nullreferenceexception

I have a wcf service which I use Miquels Castro's technique, instead of user the service reference create by VS.NET 2010.

Everything worked great until I added a new method.  When I added the new method I got a error message:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Then

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: Type
>   'System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail'
>   in Assembly 'System.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.

The code hits the proxy class:

```
public DataTable GetResearchSellingTitles(string network, string year, 
    string quarter)
{
    return Channel.GetResearchSellingTitles(network, year, quarter);
}
```

I have added the method to the interface and implemented it.  Any ideas how to determine the root of the issue?

**Update**
I solved the issue.  It had nothing to do with th WCF service setup.  What is weird is where I had where the null reference error, it was surrounded by a try catch.  I also had a log util that log the error.  I am not sure why it just didn't catch the error, log it and return a empty datatable.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: That looks like the server is getting a `NullReferenceException` and passing it to the client in an `ExceptionDetail` object, which, for some reason, is failing to serialize.

Comment: anyway to debug this? I cant seem to get at the root of the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)